# Not allowed to load local resource: JSP

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I want to download a simple file by a link  in jsp, but this name have a Chinese characters. Here my simple code :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Titre de la page</title>
  </head>
 <body>
     <a href="C:\Files\4.导轨安装板.PDF" target="_blank">My link </a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

that gives an error in navigator console : Not allowed to load local resource.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem are not the  characters is the fact that you are trying to access the local disk. Your code is executing in a browser, and, for security reasons, you cannot access the local disk of the machine on which the page is displayed. Not to mention that, if that would have been allowed, it will load something different on every machine it runs on :).
So, either you use relative path in your HREF, or full URLs.
Remember, when you specify a link it goes to  the SERVER to get the resource, not from local machine on which the browser is running.

Comment: Thank you for your response, just what can i do then to specify a absolute path in jsp file  ?

Comment: absolute path on the web means complete URL. so, you can do <a href="http://www.google.com/">link</a>. In your case, you should make that file to be available from a URL.

Comment: Thanks :) , i did it with relative path but the chinese caracters cause problem:
I have 2 file : "EE.pdf" and "导轨安装板.PDF" the first i can click it and the second give me  this error : http://localhost:8080/
SchneiderProject/4.%E5%AF%BC%E8%BD%A8%E5%AE%89%
E8%A3%85%E6%9D%BF.PDF    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Introuvable)

Comment: URLs are based only on ASCII characters. So, I advice you either to rename-it, or, if not, to have a mapping between a URL and the actual file. So when you request http://example.com/file.pdf the SERVER will give you your chinese named file.

Answer (score 0):

Do not import or load local resource in this format:

```
src="file://home/web-server/foo/bar.jpg"
```

Because modern browsers not allowed to load files on server disk.

I suggest that you tell your proxy server to server the dir

```
foo
```

as a static file dir which browsers can access via your proxy server. In NodeJS, it will be like (suggest this file in /home/web-server named app.js)

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'foo')));
```

Now, in your html code, you can call

```
<a href="4.导轨安装板.PDF" target="_blank">My link </a>
```

Then, you will see browser access your file by

```
http://yourdomain.com/4.导轨安装板.PDF
```

which will work.